# Additional include directories in Visual Studio for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I have a folder structure like this:

mother directory/Solution A/Project Aa/ file Aaa.h

mother directory/Solution B/Project Bb/ file Bbb.h

I would like to include Aaa.h in Bbb.h.

The Bbb.h looks like this:

```
#include <A/Aa/Aaa.h>

...
```

In the properties of the project Bb, I have tried C++ -> General -> Additional include directories : 
$(ProjectDir)../../../

Or I also tried 
../../../
or 
$(ProjectDir)../../..

Nothing works. I get the error message: 
"cannot open source file "A/Aa/Aaa.h".

How can I include the "Aaa.h" correctly into Bbb.h?

Comment: Have you tried backslashes in directories?

Comment: @seccpur I never use backslashes in `#include`s though I'm working in VS2013 everyday. Whatever the issue of OP is - I doubt it's caused by using "/" instead of "\\" in `#include`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the "A" directory is not inside the "B" directory, and the line `#include <A/Aa/Aaa.h>` looks for the path you gave **starting from the current directory**, so it's looking for: "B/Bb/A/Aa/Aaa.h" To resolve this, you can do one of two things.

1. Indicate the *actual* location of the Aaa.h (relative to Bbb.h) file in the include statement: `#include "../../A/Aa/Aaa.h>"` (Using such relative paths, however, will generate warnings in many compilers, as they aren't really portable.)
2. Add the directory (again, relative to the project) in the list of include folders as "../../A/Aa" and then just give the filename in the include line: `#include "Aaa.h"` (To avoid any confusion with typing in the directory path, you can just 'browse' for the actual folder from the "Properties" pop-up.)

PS: Though not strictly enforced, the custom is to use the `< >` 'quotes' for header files in *system* directories (like `#include <iostream>`) and traditional quotes for *user-supplied* headers (like `#include "Bbb.h"`).

Comment: I guess, the essential message should be: Provide an include path (in the properties applied to `Bbb.h`) where exactly the compiler can add the `A/Aa/Aaa.h` path to to find that file. (With relative paths, this can be a bit difficult to track by eyes.) Concerning the usage of angle brackets and quotes in `#include`, I don't agree fully: We use quotes exclusively for `#include` of files which are directly related to each other (e.g. a c++ source and its header which declares the things for it). We don't use quotes for headers of other libraries even if these are our own but not system headers.

Comment: @Scheff On the use of `< >` versus `" "`, it's why I called it 'custom'. But I agree that it's ultimately up to coders' and/or team policy/preference. On the search path: the second would be my preferred option: once the compiler knows to look in a given directory, there is no need to add path-specifiers in the `#include` line, which makes things generally simpler IMHO.

Comment: I would like to avoid the relative path since Aaa.h also contains the path to another header information in the solution A.

Comment: You need to check your project settings, under C++, check include directories and make sure it points to where Aaa.h. I suggest you could choose the ellipsis (...) control to browse to the correct folder. And I suggest you try to use the full path in #include.like: include "..Solution A/Project Aa/ Aaa.h"